# image with PHP GD library save JPG 300 DPI

Tags: php, gd

i am working on simple php code that write text to image . I found this code it is perfect one problem it save image into 72 dpi. I find option where i can change its DPI but not found . If any body have idea

```
      //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('pic.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'arialbd.ttf';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image,'a.jpg');

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [imageresolution()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageresolution.php) to set and get the resolution of an image in DPI (dots per inch).

**Note:** The resolution is only used as meta information when images are read from and written to formats supporting this kind of information (curently PNG and JPEG).